# UITableViewCell is empty when scroll upside in tableview

Tags: ios, swift3

- **First image when I don't scroll tableView**

MY SubItems are Show

[image: MY SubItems are Show]

- **Second Image When I scroll tableView**

MY SubItems are blank

[image: MY SubItems are blank]

My CellFor Row Code is

```
var aryDictData = [[String:AnyObject]]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var aryOptionName = [String]()
        var strOptionName = String()

        var cell = DeliveryTableViewCell()
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DeliveryTableViewCell") as! DeliveryTableViewCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none

        let productPrice = userDefault.object(forKey: ProductDesConstantNames.KAryStorePrices) as! [String]

         if indexPath.section == 0{
            if indexPath.row < (aryDictData[0]["storeName"]!).count{

               cell.lblItemName.text = ((aryDictData[0]["storeName"]! as AnyObject)[indexPath.row] as! String)

                cell.lblPrice.text = "$\(String(((Double(productPrice[indexPath.row])! + grandTotalProductPrice[indexPath.row]) * Double(numQuntity))))"

                cell.lblItemQuantity.text = "\(numQuntity)x"
                cell.lblItemQuantity.textColor = UIColor.init(red: 41/255, green: 144/255, blue: 85/255, alpha: 1.0)

                let data = aryPreviewOrder[indexPath.row] as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                print(data)

                for i in 0..<((aryDictData[0]["options"]! as AnyObject)[indexPath.row]! as AnyObject).count {
                    let optionName = ((((aryDictData[0]["options"]! as AnyObject)[indexPath.row]! as AnyObject)[i] as AnyObject)["option_name"] as! String)
                    let prices = ((((aryDictData[0]["options"]! as AnyObject)[indexPath.row]! as AnyObject)[i] as AnyObject)["price"] as! String)

                    aryOptionName.append("\(optionName) ($\(prices))")
                    //                    aryOptionPrices.append("($\(prices))")

                    strOptionName = aryOptionName.joined(separator: "\n")
                    //                    strOptionPrice = aryOptionPrices.joined(separator: "\n")
                }
                cell.lblOptionNames.text = strOptionName
               }             
           }
     }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: please add code in your cellforrow

Comment: I am working on swift 3

Comment: are you sure you are getting data  in `strOptionName` Every Time ?, write cell.layoutIfNeeded(), after cell.lblOptionNames.text = strOptionName and before that line

Comment: @Prototype remove both line : var cell = DeliveryTableViewCell()
cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DeliveryTableViewCell") as! DeliveryTableViewCell   Add this line : let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DeliveryTableViewCell") as! DeliveryTableViewCell

Comment: because strOptionName difference, may be 1 or more the one

Comment: I dont understand one thing, why the margarita Pizza and 123 label are in different color after scrolling tableview.

Comment: because by second section cell.lblOptionNames.textColor = UIColor.init(red: 41/255, green: 144/255, blue: 85/255, alpha: 1.0)

Comment: When I don't use second section at that time above issues solved, but I need Second section also

Comment: @Prototype did you try what i suggest you?, in cell for row add color to lblOptionNames label

Comment: @JonSnow, I tried but not working

Comment: Did you apply color to lblOptionNames? , and are you able to see color it after scroll ?

Comment: @JonSnow, I changed lblOptionNames background color and show but  it is not working in this sectuation.

Comment: **I changed lblOptionNames background color and show but it is not working in this sectuation**  Are you able to see color after scroll or NOT? , And if color is visible check why text is not showing ?

Comment: @JonSnow, Actually lblOptionNames can not see and background color of lblOptionNames is also can not see (blank) like above second image.

Comment: Then it  is issue of constraints please fix

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid for loops in a cell for row, while building your data source, you can create these option names and store it in an array with some key, then reuse that key every time in cellforrow, instead of creating again n again.

```
for i in 0..<((aryDictData[0]["options"]! as AnyObject)[indexPath.row]! as AnyObject).count {
  let optionName = ((((aryDictData[0]["options"]! as AnyObject)
  [indexPath.row]! as AnyObject)[i] as AnyObject)["option_name"] as! 
  String)
  let prices = ((((aryDictData[0]["options"]! as AnyObject)
  [indexPath.row]! as AnyObject)[i] as AnyObject)["price"] as! String) 
  aryOptionName.append("\(optionName) ($\(prices))")
  }
  strOptionName = aryOptionName.joined(separator: "\n")

  cell.lblOptionNames.text = strOptionName
```